# Capture event of core-header-panel menu collapse

Tags: web, polymer

I want to capture the event of a Polymer/core-header-panel menu collapsing (while changing the size of the window). But i don´t have any idea of how to do it.

Comment: do you mean the side-menu? Like the one in [core-scaffold](https://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-scaffold/demo.html)?

Comment: Yes, thats it. thx! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use the *on-core-responsive-change* event. It depends on what you are using.

**core-scaffold**

```
<core-scaffold on-core-responsive-change='{{myFunction}}'>
```

**core-drawer**

```
<core-drawer on-core-responsive-change='{{myFunction}}'>
```